# Construction of ultrafilters in Heyting Algebras

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, filters

Let $$f: H\rightarrow Z_{2}$$ be a Heyting Algebra homomorphism. Could anyone explain why $$f^{-1}(1)$$ is an ultrafilter? I know that it's a prime ideal.  It's not clear to me because complementation in Heyting Algebras isn't particularly well-behaved.  Thank you, Paul Epstein.

Comment: What do you mean by ultrafilter? A maximal filter?

Comment: Yes, according to my reading, an ultrafilter, by definition, is a filter that is maximal with respect to set inclusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $F$ be a filter on $H$ and let $h\in H$ with:$$f^{-1}(1)\subseteq F\text{ and }h\in F-f^{-1}(1)$$

Then: $$f(h\to0)=f(h)\to f(0)=0\to0=1$$ so that also $h\to0\in F$.

But then $0=h\wedge(h\to0)\in F$ implying that $F$ is not a proper filter and equals $H$.

Proved is now that $f^{-1}(1)$ cannot be contained in a proper filter that is larger than $f^{-1}(1)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot drhab.  It tends to be easy (for me) to follow these arguments but difficult for me to know which trick to try.  It comes with experience and practice.  I have just proved the converse:  If you start with an ultrafilter in a Heyting algebra, then the characteristic function of the ultrafilter gives you the homomorphism.  This was tricky for me, but I got there on my own.

Comment: Congratulations ;-). Glad to help.